# add visual constraints to UITableViewCell so that the UIView occupies the entire cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I am adding a UIView to a UITableViewCell using the code below

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.mTravelSearchView];
```

The travel search view appears in the cell. In the interface builder I have added correct constraints to self.mTravelSearchView so everything within this view renders correctly.

However I believe I need to programmatically add constraints so that the mTravelSearchView occupies the entire cell as at present it doesn't.

I have tried the below code, but the width of the view is wrong still and only uses a portion of the cell. What am I doing wrong?

```
    [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[travelSearch]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"travelSearch" : self.mTravelSearchView}]];
    [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[travelSearch]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"travelSearch" : self.mTravelSearchView}]];
```

I'm not really familiar with programmatically adding the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found that I needed this line

```
self.mTravelSearchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```